# How to restart nginx using circle CI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, circleci

I have a rails application deployed using circle CI, after every commit the changes are automatically build by circle CI, but I want to restart nginx server, I have added "`sudo service nginx restart`" in my circle.yml it gives error like

```
error: sudo service nginx restart returned exit code 1

nginx: unrecognized service
Action failed: sudo service nginx restart
```

I also tried the following in config/deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute :sudo, "service nginx restart"
    end
  end
```

still nginx server doesn't get restarted?

Comment: Hey, please get in touch with us at sayhi(at)circleci(dot)com or via the in-app messenger—I’m sure we’ll get this sorted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to start nginx with `circle.yml` is failing because the command will be run on the CI server, not your intended web server.

Not sure why the attempt to restart with Capistrano is failing.

If you are using passenger with nginx, another way to restart nginx server on a rails app is to create/modify a `tmp/restart.txt` file in the app directory.

See [3.4. Redeploying (restarting the Rack application)](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_rack_application)
 and [How do i make nginx and passenger restart automatically after a deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915985/how-do-i-make-nginx-and-passenger-restart-automatically-after-a-deploy) for the explanation.

The following code snippet in `config/deploy.rb` implements the logic:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Restart Application"
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end 
  end 
end
```